# Clustering structured data

Tags: clustering, predictive-models, cluster-sample

Does clustering make sense at structured data? I have a sales data set from a retail company. The data is structured into Product Lines, Product Groups and Colors and Articles.

I wanted to make a cluster analysis to find similar articles or colors, on which I can make a time series analysis and build my predictive model on.

Clustering the data with k-means or two-step algorithm will bring probably each product line as a cluster. Right?

Comment: It ALL depends on the distance you will consider for clustering. One could probably achieve all possible partitions of your data provided a particular choice of clustering algorithm/distance/representation/normalization/projections of your data.

Comment: If you have sales data, do you also have a customer id? Because then clustering might show which customers bought the same kind products / productgroups. Also first check your time series to see how everything looks before you start modeling.

Comment: @phiver Nope. I dont have any personal data like Customer ID or user. Just Store, Article, its Product Group, its Product line,  Price, and Amount.

Comment: @phiver btw to "check time series" I need first to choose a product group or article. Without doing it, all data is mixed up and its not a time series. For example I have in one product group many articles which were sold more than one time in a month. So this month comes up already 3-4 times in the data set.

Comment: At least you can have a look if there are clusters with regards to the stores. Clustering on the products might give you some insight in which products / product colors are likely sold together in certain months. You can also check if there are any seasonal effects in the monthly sales data.

Comment: @phiver Yes...I tried clustering with different parameters. I got for example black shirts as a cluster. What kind of analysis I can make with that cluster? Time series?

Answer (score 0):

Cluster analysis cannot do magic.

It's not as if these tools will just work and yield the desired result.

On contrary, **doing cluster analysis right will require many iterations**. It is an exploratory technique with many parameters. You need to carefully study the results, then change parameters as to make them more understandable, repeat.

A clustering algorithm *may* (unless you control parameterd well) divide the products into two clusters:

- products with an even-length name
- products with an odd-length name

That is why it's part of *explorative data analysis*: it's a method for exploring data. Exploration will have may dead ends, and then you need to go back and try something different.

Comment: Yes man, I agree. but think of it in the way of a thesis. You need to explore something interesting. Not only play around with different parameters. My question was, if there can be other clusters. So far the analysis shows me a cluster = a product line.

Comment: You can only find other clusterd by experimenting. Usually, cluster analysis orefers the obvious.